# java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:

Tags: java, bucles, excepciones, parsear

En el siguiente fragmento de código, estoy intentando controlar que dada una opción("opcion") insertada por teclado como String, la opción no salga del rango del ArrayList de objetos "prolist" y que además la opción sea numérica. Pero en cuanto inserto un carácter alfabético me salta la excepción: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:

¿Hay alguna manera de resolver esto sin hacer uso de try/catch?

```
                int numero;
                boolean esNumerico=true;
                do {
                    System.out.println("");                             
                    System.out.print("Elige un producto: ");                    
                    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    opcion = sc2.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("");
                    
                    opcion.trim();
                    opcion.replace(" ","");
                    
                    numero = Integer.parseInt(opcion);
                    
                    for(int i=0;i<opcion.length();i++){
                          if(opcion.charAt(i)<48 || opcion.charAt(i)>57 || numero>prolist.size()) {                             
                                esNumerico=false;
                                System.out.println("OPCIÓN NO VÁLIDA");
                            }
                    }               
                    
            
                }while(esNumerico==false);
```

Comment: Hay algunos paquetes que podrías importar, como `StringUtils` o [`NumberUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/math/NumberUtils.html#isParsable-java.lang.String-) que permiten hacer ese tipo de comprobaciones. Pero es más fácil usar la excepción. Las excepciones en este caso son muy prácticas, puesto que un try/catch **no afecta al rendimiento** mientras no se lance ninguna excepción. Si quieres evitar la excepción, otra opción sería usar el `Integer.parseInt` después de comprobar que *SI* es un número, después de tu bucle...

Comment: Gracias por la aportación. El no querer usa try/catch es simplemente porque no me lo permiten(sólo puedo utilizar técnicas contempladas en los temas previos que he estudiado), pero no es que no me guste la solución. He probado a a usar el Integer.parseInt después de comprobar si es número, pero me lanza otra de tipo java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Seguiré probando.

Comment: ` java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` es simplemente porque estás intentando acceder a un índice que no existe en tu array (o string). Revisa el bucle :)

Comment: Perdón, la excepción nueva es de tipo  java.lang.NullPointerException, y no la de  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. , me he equivocado :(

Comment: Sin más información es imposible ayudarte. Pero la NPE ***SIEMPRE*** es porque estás usando un objeto ***ANTES*** de *inicializarlo*. Además, en el stacktrace que te imprime en consola te dirá exactamente qué objeto y en qué línea, no tienes más que leer el error.

Answer (score 0):

El problema estaba en usar simultáneamente la comprobación de si "opcion" era alfabético y la comprobación de si "opcion" era mayor que el rango del ArrayList mediante el parseo, así que con if/else ha funcionado:

```
                do {
                    
                    menuProductos(prolist);
                    
                    System.out.println("");                             
                    System.out.print("Elige un producto: ");                    
                    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
                    opcion = sc2.nextLine();
                    System.out.println("");
                    
                    opcion.trim();
                    opcion.replace(" ","");
                                        
                    for(int w=0;w<opcion.length();w++){
                         if(opcion.charAt(w)<48 || opcion.charAt(w)>57) {   
                                                    
                                esNumerico=false;
                                System.out.println("OPCIÓN NO VÁLIDA");
                         }else {
                                numero = Integer.parseInt(opcion);
                                if(numero>prolist.size()) {
                                    esNumerico=false;
                                    System.out.println("OPCIÓN NO VÁLIDA, NÚMERO FUERA DE RANGO");
                                }
                         }
                    }
                                        
                                                        
                }while(esNumerico==false);
```